# Rails many-to-many creation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have event and band models, which have a many-to-many relationship through event_bands. I am trying to change my create method to use `chosen jQuery` like in [episode 258 of railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised). I am not sure how to read the message from my localhost when I try to create an event:

```
Started POST "/events" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-16 17:11:07 +0900
Processing by EventsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Jx1Cm09uCwJcnY8573ZTRKMjH1BHWhlREFCfhij/AB0=",  "event"=>{"name"=>"pojpj", "ko_name"=>"", "band_ids"=>["", "110"], "venue_id"=>"", "date(1i)"=>"2014", "date(2i)"=>"3", "date(3i)"=>"16", "time"=>"", "contact"=>"", "facebook"=>"", "ticket"=>"true", "price"=>"", "door_price"=>"", "ticket_url"=>"", "info"=>"", "info_ko"=>""}, "commit"=>"등록", "locale"=>"ko"}
Band Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "bands".* FROM "bands" WHERE "bands"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 110]]
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
Band Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "bands" WHERE ("bands"."name" = '...Whatever That   Means' AND "bands"."id" != 110) LIMIT 1
(0.2ms)  rollback transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/events/new
```

It looks like it fails because the Band already exists in the database, but why is it doing that instead of creating the relation?

```
def new
    @event = Event.new
end

def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    if @event.save
        flash[:notice] = "Event Created!"
        redirect_to event_path(@event)
    else
        flash[:notice] = "Event not created!"
        redirect_to new_event_path
    end
end
    private

  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:name,
        :ko_name,
        :avatar,
        :time,
        :facebook,
        :ticket,
        :door_price,
        :ticket_url,
        :info_kr, 
        :contact, 
        :price,
        :info,
        :info_ko, 
        :venue_id, 
        :date,
        band_ids: [])
  end
```

Relevant part of the form:

```
<p>
    <%= f.label "Bands" %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :band_ids, Band.order(:name), :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true} %>
</p>
```

I have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :bands` in the model and I think the relation is setup correctly because I can do `a = Event.new(name: 'asdf', band_ids: [1,5])  a.save` and it is persisted.

update: it seems the problem is coming from the empty item in `band_ids`. For some reason, rails is setting the param as `band_ids: ['',3,5]`. I can replicate the SQL message from my server by trying to create a new entry in the console like this: `a = Event.create(name: 'asdfasdfasdfasdf2345', band_ids: ['', 3, 2])`.  But where is the empty first item coming from?

edit2: Disregard the above, it seems the problem is actually that there is no `event_id` to use in the association?

```
@messages={:"event_bands.event_id"=>["에 내용을 입력해 주세요"]}
```

Comment: Try changing `f.collection_select :band_ids` to `f.collection_select :band_id`

Comment: that gives ```undefined method `band_id' for #<Event:0x007fd4e26aa8d8>```

Comment: Okay, so if I remove ```validates :event_id, presence: true``` from ```event_bands```, then this form submits and creates the relations correctly. I'm stumped: I'd really like to keep the validations in there